# Bundler claims to install current version of formtastic, but bundle open shows it contains deprecated method that should have been removed already

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, formtastic

First time posting on SO, please forgive me and let me know if there's anything I can do to make this question better.

I'm working on a rails 4 app using the formtastic gem. When I put a boolean input in my form, requesting the page throws an error:

```
undefined method `check_box_checked?' for ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag:Class
```

Googling uncovered this PR which should have removed the deprecated method 'check_box_checked?' months ago: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/pull/915

Here's the output of bundle show

```
djhrtmn@porygon:~/dev/casey$ bundle show formtastic
/home/djhrtmn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/formtastic-2.2.1
```

So it looks like I'm using the right version... but when I bundle open the gem 'check_box_checked?' is still there.

Let me know if there's anything else I can do to improve the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PR you linked did remove the deprecated method months ago, but version 2.2.1 of Formtastic (which is indeed the current stable version) was actually released over a year ago. You can see this by switching to the [2.2.1 tag](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/tree/2.2.1) in the GitHub repository and noting the last commit was on June 6th, 2012. To fully confirm, you can drill down to [the file in question](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/2.2.1/lib/formtastic/inputs/boolean_input.rb#L99) and see that the old code is still there.

If you're having issues with this method call, the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/CHANGELOG) indicates there is a Release Candidate available for a newer version (RCs are generally stable but not quite considered "ready for primetime" yet). You could upgrade by manually specifying version `2.3.0.rc2` in your Gemfile.

Comment: Wow that seems really odd that they would be using a method that isn't in Rails 4 in the latest stable version... rc2 doesn't use the method and updating to it did work. Thanks so much, especially for the tip about sorting by tag, I was totally mystified about why the method was in my gem but not on github.

Comment: Oddly, the README explicitly claims the 2.2 series is compatible with Rails 4. The issue you linked must have slipped through the cracks.